Switching users in tic tac toe game
I am currently working on tic tac toe project with javascript html css.
The problem is I did set the constructors by the input of the user but
I cannot switch over the user when I play my game
My expectations are be able to switch user when you play your turn.
I tried if else by assigning currentplayer to player 1 if player 1 - I want to change it to player2


const gameBoard = (function() {
  // Select DOM elements
  const playerInput1 = document.querySelector("#player-select1");
  const playerButton = document.querySelector(".add-player");
  const playerInput2 = document.querySelector("#player-select2");
  const playerPara1 = document.querySelector(".player1");
  const playerPara2 = document.querySelector(".player2");
  const showPlayers = document.querySelector(".player-shows");
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

  // Game markers
  const gameMarker = ["O", "X"];
  let currentPlayer;
  let player1, player2;

  // Player factory function
  const playerSelection = (name, marker) => {
    let score = 0;
    return {
      name,
      marker,
      getScore: function() {
        return score;
      },
      scorePlus: function() {
        score++;
        return score;
      }
    };
  };

  // Initialize players
  player1 = playerSelection("Name", gameMarker[0]);
  player2 = playerSelection("Name", gameMarker[1]);

  // Event listener for player names
  playerButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    player2.name = playerInput2.value.trim();
    player1.name = playerInput1.value.trim();

    if (player1.name === "" || player2.name === "") {
      alert("Please enter a name");
    } else {
      playerPara1.textContent = `First Player is: ${player1.name} (${player1.marker})`;
      playerPara2.textContent = `Second Player is: ${player2.name} (${player2.marker})`;
      showPlayers.innerHTML = "";
      showPlayers.append(playerPara1);
      showPlayers.append(playerPara2);

      // Start the game by setting the initial player
      playGame();
    }
  });

  // Add event listeners to boxes
  boxes.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (element.textContent === "" && currentPlayer) { // Ensure box is empty and a player is set
        element.textContent = currentPlayer.marker; // Mark the box with the current player's marker
        playGame(); // Switch to the next player
      }
    });
  });

  // Function to switch current player
  const playGame = () => {
    if (currentPlayer === player1) {
      player1
    } else if (currentPlayer === player2) {
      player2
    }


  };

  // Return public methods
  return {
    playerSelection,
    playGame
  };
})();
<input type="text" id="player-select1">
<buttton class="add-player">Add</button>
<input type="text" id="player-select2">
<p class="player1"></p>
<p class="player2"></p>

<div class="player-shows"></div>

<div id="board">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<br>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<br>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<br>
</div>




You are not assigning anything to currentPlayer

I made you a snippet. Please click [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and add RELEVANT HTML and CSS to have a [mcve]

@mplungjan thanks for converting it into a snippet, otherwise I would have probably not even started writing an answer.

I used @mplungjan's snippet as the point of departure. First, I fixed the CSS so we can actually see something. Next, I have realized that you check whether current player equals with player1 in which case you evaluate to player1 instead of setting the current player to player2 and vice versa, second, you missed the initial initialization, you need to handle the case when current player is still undefined, finally, you are calling game play upon any click as well as upon clicking on a square, so you are switching the player twice when someone clicks on a box, because it's a click on a box as well as a click per se.


const gameBoard = (function() {
  // Select DOM elements
  const playerInput1 = document.querySelector("#player-select1");
  const playerButton = document.querySelector(".add-player");
  const playerInput2 = document.querySelector("#player-select2");
  const playerPara1 = document.querySelector(".player1");
  const playerPara2 = document.querySelector(".player2");
  const showPlayers = document.querySelector(".player-shows");
  const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".box");

  // Game markers
  const gameMarker = ["O", "X"];
  let currentPlayer;
  let player1, player2;

  // Player factory function
  const playerSelection = (name, marker) => {
    let score = 0;
    return {
      name,
      marker,
      getScore: function() {
        return score;
      },
      scorePlus: function() {
        score++;
        return score;
      }
    };
  };

  // Initialize players
  player1 = playerSelection("Name", gameMarker[0]);
  player2 = playerSelection("Name", gameMarker[1]);

  // Event listener for player names
  playerButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    showPlayers.innerHTML = "";
    player2.name = playerInput2.value.trim();
    player1.name = playerInput1.value.trim();

    if (player1.name === "" || player2.name === "") {
      showPlayers.innerHTML = "Please add two players to start";
      return;
    }  
    playerPara1.textContent = `First Player is: ${player1.name} (${player1.marker})`;
    playerPara2.textContent = `Second Player is: ${player2.name} (${player2.marker})`;
    
    showPlayers.append(playerPara1);
    showPlayers.append(playerPara2);
    currentPlayer = player1; // initialise

  });

  // Add an event listener to the board
  board.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let element = e.target.closest('.box'); // handle nested elements
    if (!element || !currentPlayer || element.textContent.trim() !== "") return;
    element.textContent = currentPlayer.marker;
    playGame();
  });
  // Function to switch current player - using a ternary
  const playGame = () =>  currentPlayer = (currentPlayer === player2) ? player1 : player2;

  // Return public methods
  return {
    playerSelection,
    playGame
  };
})();
#board {
  display: table;
}

#board .row {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  background-color: gray;
  font-size: xx-large;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
<input type="text" id="player-select1" placeholder="please enter a name">
<button class="add-player">Add</button>
<input type="text" id="player-select2" placeholder="please enter a name">
<p class="player1"></p>
<p class="player2"></p>

<div class="player-shows">Please add two players to start</div>

<div id="board">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>




Please delegate: board.addEventListener("click", (e) => { let element = e.target.closest('.box'); if (!element || !currentPlayer || element.textContent.trim() !== "") return;  element.textContent = currentPlayer.marker;  playGame();  });

@mplungjan currently I'm very busy. I will try to get back to this later today if I do not forget. Please feel free to edit the answer as long as its quality does not drop and if you wish to do so.If not, then  (I hope) I will return to it :)

Ok, I refactored a bit since I vastly prefer delegation. I also simplified the toggle of players

@mplungjan thanks for the edit. I noticed that if you click on the squares the 0 and the X is no longer added to them, which was working before. It's a crazy day here, but I will fix this when I have time

The script works. You need to add two players before it runs

@mplungjan aaah, you mean clicking on the add button. Earlier it was enough to fill the inputs. I stand corrected, thanks.

You did have to click the add names first to get the players set up.

@mplungjan in fact you could have clicked anywhere and then the game started. Never mind. It looks good now and thanks for the edit.
